# Como excluir um elemento de um Array String?

Tags: python, array, string, lista

Estou tendo o seguinte erro de compilação:

> ```
> del(alimentos[i])  
> TypeError: 'str' object doesn't support item deletion
> ```

O que fiz de errado? Gostaria de remover o elemento digitado da lista.

Meu código:

```
dieta = []
alimentos = ""
comer = ""

while len(dieta) is not 26:
    alimentos = input("Qual o alimento? ")
    if alimentos == "fim":
        break
    dieta.append(alimentos)

i = 0
while i <= len(dieta):
    comer = input("Qual alimento deseja comer? ")
    if comer in dieta:
         print("pode comer")
         del(alimentos[i])
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu código está um pouco errado.

Ele está deletando de acordo com o `i`, mas e se eu não quiser deletar o primeiro elemento? ( `0` ) e sim o segundo ( `1` )? Afinal, ele deleta o que eu "como", certo?

E também o erro ocorre por que está tentando tirar um elemento de uma string, e não uma lista.

Eu mudei um pouco e deixei assim :

Você também não precisa declarar a variável `alimentos` nem `comer` no começo.

Pode por `While 1:` ou `While True:` para que ele fique rodando até você digitar "fim".

```
dieta = []

while 1: # Infinito
    alimentos = input("Qual o alimento? Digite 'fim' para encerrar")
    if alimentos == "fim":
        break
    else:
        dieta.append(alimentos)

while 1: # Infinito
    if len(dieta) == 0: # Se a lista esvaziar, ele encerra, senão, ele continua.
        print('Acabou a lista.')
        break
    else:
        print(dieta)
        comer = input("Qual alimento deseja comer? ")
        if comer in dieta:
            print("pode comer")
            deletar = dieta.index(comer) # Posição do item que quer deletar.
            del(dieta[deletar])
        else:
            print('Não pode comer')
```

Comment: Deu erro no seu código Antony. Olha o print: http://imgur.com/a/6O7gR

Comment: Aqui rodou tranquilo, não sei o que deu errado aí não. Acabei de testar aqui.

Comment: O código postado aqui está ok mesmo, da uma olhada nele rodando aqui https://repl.it/HwO4/0

Comment: Pra mim continua dando o erro... NameError: name 'peixe' is not defined, como se eu tivesse que definir a variável peixe que é a minha entrada '-'

Comment: Você tá usando o meu código ou está usando o seu com algumas modificações baseados no meu? Se for a segunda opção tente usar o meu código apenas e veja o que acontece. Se não for o caso, eu não sei o que é, por que aqui tá tranquilo.

Comment: Estou usando o seu código. E também gostaria de saber o problema, pois não faz sentido.

Comment: Obrigado galera, consegui resolver o problema: Atualizei o Python do meu PC do 2.7 para o 3.6. E Desinstalei o PyCharm, excluindo tudo que havia no antigo, e instalei novamente a versão mais recente selecionando o intérprete 3.6 no PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar o *remove* caso tenha mais de um valor igual na lista, ele remove a primeira ocorrência encontrada,
fiz um teste com apenas um while

```
def cadastrar():
    dieta = []

    while True:
        if(dieta):
            print(dieta)    
        alimento = input("'fim' para encerrar \n'consumir' para comer \nQual o alimento: ").lower()
        if alimento == 'fim':
            break
        elif alimento == 'consumir':
            if(dieta):
                print(dieta)
                comer = input("Digite o alimento para consumir : ").lower()
                if comer in dieta:
                    print("pode comer")
                    dieta.remove(comer)
                else:
                    print("Não pode comer")
            else:
                print('Não tem alimentos para comer')
        else:
            dieta.append(alimento)
    return dieta
```